# How to create a Eclipse Product based on the Eclipse Java Edition?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I would like to create an Eclipse Product based on the ["Eclipse IDE for Java Developers"](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2023-09/r/eclipse-ide-java-developers), to create a branded version (custom splash screen, icons, ...). My goal is to have the same features than this Edition, and add some customization.
I was able to create my Eclipse Product, mainly with the help of [this tutorial](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseProductDeployment/article.html), but this requires to manually select the features
or the plugins of the Eclipse IDE for Java Developers. This is quite error-prone and requires to check for each Edition upgrade if the list of features has changed.

Is there a way to configure the Eclipse Product project to start from the Eclipse IDE for Java Developers explicitly?

Comment: If you did, you'd be starting with the "Java Edition" productization included as well.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "manually select the features or the plugins of the Java edition". Could you please give an example what you mean by that? With [Eclipse JustJ](https://eclipse.dev/justj/) you can include a Java VM as a feature in your RCP application.

Comment: @howlger I mean the "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers" available here: https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2023-09/r/eclipse-ide-java-developers. I'd like to create a product which contains all the "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers" features and brand it (splash screen, ...). I tried to add all the features listed in this page and I wanted to know of there is a way to just say "Use the feature 'xxx' which contains all the features of this edition". It would make it easier to configure, and make upgrade easier too (no need to check if the list of features have changed for example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Eclipse Packaging Project](https://eclipse.org/epp) provides all needed to build the the *Eclipse IDE for Java Developers* and other IDE packages in the following GitHub repository (see e.g. [the product definition file of the *Eclipse IDE for Java Developers*](https://github.com/eclipse-packaging/packages/blob/master/packages/org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product/epp.product)):
**https://github.com/eclipse-packaging/packages**

You might also have a look at my custom Eclipse Java IDE, called [***IDEalized***](https://github.com/howlger/IDEalized).

You can use one of them as a starting point to build your own customized Eclipse IDE.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers! These are indeed very good starting points to do what I want.